# Does „at least one“ mean a four?

Tags: claims, interpretation

The independent claim declares „comprising … at least one support.“

The dependent claim state „a body joined to said support.“

Does the dependent claim cover a body that is joined to, say, four supports?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
It would even suffice to say "comprising a support, the body joined to the support."

It means the device has a support which is connected to the body. One with 4 supports still has 1 support that is connected to the body -> 4 times.

Also, if the description doesn't hint otherwise, the interpretation that a support may have 4 pieces could be possible. (In this case, "at least one" *could* be a hint otherwise.)